# How to create a video collection in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I would like to add some videos to my site. I have a page so far called Library where all the videos will be for each category.

How I would like it to work is you select a category, which then takes you to another page with subcategories on with a list of videos relating to that subcategory you then select a video and it takes you to a video pagewhich then plays the chosen video.

I have began creating a Video table with the following attributes:

- id
- title
- category
- slug
- youtube or vimeo link
- duration

I have looked at Video players and I have decided to use VideoJS

I basically need help with getting stated and where best to start.

Comment: "I basically need help with getting stated on Models and Controllers." So read the documentation on models and controllers.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you could probably do this, this is how I would do it.

To link the videos across categories and subcategories you would need a couple of tables/models

> Video.php
>
> Category.php
>
> SubCategory.php

**Tables**

> **Categories**
>
> categoryID
>
> category_name
>
> **SubCategories**
>
> subcategoryID
>
> subcategory_name
>
> *categoryID*
>
> **videos**
>
> videoID 
>   video_name
>
> slug link
>
> duration
>
> *subcategoryID*

You could have one controller that performed the methods for you, or separate them, depending on how many functions you are going to have etc.

I would have methods to do the following

- Show your page with a list of all the categories for example would need to contain something like

  ```
  public function getCategories()
  {
      $categories = Category::all()->lists('category_name', 'categoryID');
      return view('categories')->with(compact(categories));
  }
  ```
- Show your next page with the subcategories and its videos

  ```
  public function getSubCategories($categoryID)
  {
      //get all subcategories that relate to selected category and their videos
      $subcategories = SubCategory::join('videos', 'subcategories.subcategoryID', '=', 'videos.subcategoryID')->where('subcategories.categoryID', '=', $categoryID)->get();
  }
  ```

Then return this data to your view. Bare in mind this may not be exact for your solution as I quickly just threw this together, but hopefully steers you in the right direction.